# Sandy bridge sockets

Tags: cpu, sockets

what is the difference between these two socket types: bga 1023 and rpga 988b

asking because now I have i3-2310m which is bga 1023 type CPU before that I had Intel b970 CPU which had rpga 988b socket type.

the thing is that CPUBoss homepage says that they are two different cpu's and they have different socket types [image below]

[bga 1023 vs rpga 988b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMZma.png)

however after i switched to i3 it is working just fine but the problem is my laptop is turning off exactly every 30 minutes, I even started timer on my phone.

it has nothing to do with bios version. I think something is triggering that 30 minutes timer. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I noticed the same issue (different sockets reported) on cpubenchmark.net when comparing i7-3632QM and i5-3320M CPUs.

If you check the specs on Intel's website you'll see that the CPU is available for both socket types.

https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/sku/52220/intel-core-i32310m-processor-3m-cache-2-10-ghz/specifications.html

Answer (score 2):

BGA 1023 stands for "ball grid array with 1023 pins", it is not a socket - the chip is soldered directly to the motherboard.
rPGA 988b is also known as Socket G2, which in turn is a real socket for mobile processors.

Periodic turning off has nothing to do with these, it is either:

- a hardware fault (for example - CPU may be installed/soldered poorly and overheat or loose stability for similar reasons, but these are usually occur at random times)
- a software timer, for example - a power saving plan in the OS. Most modern OSes have this enabled by default so idling PC goes to sleep or turns off completely

Since the interval is exactly 30 minutes - most probably it is the latter.